# How to use $ (dollar sign) ^(exponent sign) in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I saw a YAML file that includes some signs like $, ^. For $, I think it tries to get value from a JSON file. But for ^, I'm not sure about that.

I tried to search for the YAML syntax but cannot find the usage of those signs.

Could anyone point out where that usage from? Thanks a lot!

examples:

```
      json: $.A.Documents[*]
      input: ^.B.ID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YAML doesn't assign any special meaning to those characters. As far as YAML is concerned, they are simply part of the content.

Of course, the software loading that YAML can do anything with the loaded data – including inspecting the loaded scalars for `$` and `^` and implementing some action on them.

While someone might be able to correctly guess which software expects a YAML file like the one you show, it would be vastly easier for you to check the context in which you found that YAML file. This should lead you to the information you seek – i.e., for which software that YAML file has been written. That software's documentation will then describe how those characters are processed.